# Export to csv, field stretching to another page issue - Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-csv

I have table component inside summary band. One of the columns contains large text content.

In cases when value in that column is large, field stretch to another page. There is option, for fields, to not print value if details overflow page and it will prevent other fields repetition on second page. That's expected and fine for me.

Issue is that when I export a report in csv, it creates new row for data that is stretched to new page. For excel format export is fine.

Example

```
page 1

column1   column2  column3
   1         2      test test
                    test test
                    test test

page 2

column1   column2  column3
                    test test
```

It will produce the following output in csv

```
1,2, test test
     test test
     test test 
,, test test
```

How to remove these commas and make column3 data as one item. I assume that somehow I have to prevent pagination for csv export, but setting any of the provided report properties did not solve me issue.

Anyone have idea, experience?

Thanks

Comment: <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
try this property in your jrxml.

Comment: if you using java code to fill your report then you can set the parameter at the time of export means use IS_IGNORE PAGINATION only when you are using csv export else do not use it. Or you can set the Split Type property to prevent on band. Click on band then you can see split type set it to prevent but this method may create some problem with other export.